# running a python script and using its output file from another python script

Tags: python, subprocess

using python 3.6
I have two python scripts each in a diffrent folder.
eg X/p1.py and Y/p2.py
p2 creates an output file (called out.txt)
I want to run p2 from p1 and use the output file i got from p2 inside p1.
I tried this:

```
import subprocess
input_file = subprocess.run(["Y/out.txt"])
```

rest of the code is reding the file and using it for creating lists and more.
But it didnt worked and Im not able to read the file.
would love to hear another ways.
thank you

Comment: If you're running the above code from folder `X`, your path needs to be something like `"../Y/out.txt"`. But are you sure you want to run a .txt file?

Comment: There is already a better way to run Python from Python, and that is by importing a module. Just return the results from p1.py as Python values; no need to read and parse anything from a file.

Comment: If you just want to *read* the .txt file, use `with open("../Y/out.txt", "r) as f: ...`

Answer (score 0):

With that instruction you are trying to run a txt file. Apart from this are you sure you need subprocess? Isn't it enough to import p2 in p1 and call the function that generates out.txt? Like:

```
from path_to_p2 import function

def use_output_from_p2():
    function()
    with open ("Y/out.txt","r") as f:
        #do whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to run "Y/p2.py" first. Then you want to check for the existence of the out.txt file and try to read it

```py
import subprocess
import os.path

input_file = subprocess.run(["Y/p2.py"])

output_file = "Y/out.txt"
assert os.path.isfile(output_file)

with open(output_file, "r") as output_f:
   ....
```